# transactions : T1: read(A); read(B); if A = 0 then B := B + 1; write(B). T2: read(B); read(A); if B = 0 then A := A + 1; write(A)

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me solve and understand  these?

Consider the following two transactions

T1:

```
read(A);
read(B);
if A = 0 then B := B + 1;
write(B).
```

T2:

```
read(B);
read(A);
if B = 0 then A := A + 1;
write(A).
```

A- Add lock and unlock instructions to transactions T1 and T2, so that they observe the two-phase locking protocol.

Use the lock-S and lock-X notation as defined below:

```
-Shared Lock.
```

If a transaction T has obtained a shared-mode lock (denotedby lock-S) on item Q, thenT  can read, but cannot write, Q. 2.

```
-Exclusive Lock.
```

If a transaction T  has obtained an exclusive-mode lock (denoted by lock-X) on item Q, thenT can both read and write Q.

B- Can the execution of these transactions result in a deadlock?  Give an example if it can.